# Click Button From Specific id

Tags: javascript, html

I was hoping someone could help me with some javascript that would click on this button:

```
<div tabindex="0" role="button" id="id_72229384732282" class="collapsed focus-visible" data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton" aria-label="Filter rows">
```

I can't use the id_7222.... because this is dynamic and changes after a page refresh. Is there a way to click this button based on the id="filterButton"?

Thanks!

I've tried all sorts of methods but I know my syntax or the class reference is wrong. Here are the general ones I've tried:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('filterButton').click();
```

```
document.getElementById("filterButton");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the id is dynamic and you can't use it, you can use class to select the element.
Your html element has `collapsed focus-visible` class.
If you don't want to use it, and rather use **filterButton**, you should edit your html and add **filterButton** to classes.
(currently on your html, 'filterButton' is not defined among classes. )

```html
<div tabindex="0" role="button" id="id_72229384732282" class="collapsed focus-visible filterButton" data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton" aria-label="Filter rows">
```

then you can select it on JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('filterButton').click();
// or 
document.querySelector('div.filterButton').click();
```

IF you can't touch/ edit your html, then you should select your element like this, (**as @mplungjan also points out**')

```
// if there are more than one element with the same dataset key-value pair, 
// this selection selects the 1st of those elements
document.querySelector('div[data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton"]').click();
```

---

#### SideNote:

`data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton"` is a 'data' attribute.
[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

It is used to store data on html and can be retrieved in JavaScript side using keyword `dataset`

```
let theButton = document.querySelector('div.filterButton')

// Note hyphen changed to camelCase
theButton.dataset.tutorialSelectorId'] // 'filterButton'
```

On CSS side, you can use this data attribute as a selector

```css
div[data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton"]{

background:red;
}
```

Comment: I gave you a credit.

Comment: Your first comments are no longer relevant

Comment: @D.H Thank you so much for the complete explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the `s` in getElement`s`ByClassName? That means it is plural and returns a collection. You would need to index your way to the button, so it would be  `document.getElementsByClassName('focus-visible')[0].click()` - because you cannot use getElementsByClassName to get at a data attribute

Instead you can use

```
document.querySelector['[data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton"]').click()
```

which will click the FIRST element with that attribute and value

If you have more than one element with the attribute `data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton"`, then you need to be more specific.

```
document.querySelector['div[data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton"]').click()
```

will click the first DIV with that attribute and

```
document.querySelectorAll['div[data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton"]')[1].click()
```

will click the SECOND div with that attribute (the collection returned by querySelectorAll is 0 based)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I needed the additional 'div' as specified in @d-h comment below for it to work with my particular HTML.

Comment: That is REALLY strange. So you have more than one element with `[data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton"]` ? And one of those is not a div? That was not clear from your description where you wanted to click a `button` based on the `data-tutorial-selector-id="filterButton"` which seems to indicate there is only one element with that attribute. Anyway see update